# JSONP and AngularJS

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, jsonp

I'm developing software to integrate into a router, like the rest of our stack it's developed using AngularJS, the router manufacturer has an API built into the router which returns JSON(P?).

To be a pain, they've prefixed the JSON response with

```
while(1);
```

Then commented out the JSON response, within the (minified) code they've written it is using this, so there is a way to access the data.

Whenever I try (using ngResource) it's just running the while(1); function and causing the browser to crash.

HTTP Response:

```
while(1); /*[{"username":"admin",
              "userlevel":2,
              "promptinfo":"",
              "enableprompt":false,
              "ID":"InternetGatewayDevice.UserInterface.X_Web.UserInfo.1.",
              "FirstLogin":1}]*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you use `http.get` instead ? Meaning is the call made to the same domain that you run it on ? If so, you could parse out the response for anything before and and the `[]` ?